# android SensorEventListener problem

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to create an application which reads data from digital compass. I tried to reuse the code from the book Professional Android Application Development but the IDE displayed a note

> The type SensorListener is deprecated

I guess it is because the code from the book is written for the earlier SDK version so I tried to use SensorEventListener instead.

Then when I tried to register the listener

```
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

an error appeared:

> The method registerListener(SensorListener, int, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (SensorEventListener, int, int)

so I tried to cast SensorEventListener to SensorListener, but the application doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to use sensor in newer SDK versions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a separate [`SensorEventListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html) class you need to use. See [here](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Sensor/Shaker/).

Answer (score 6):

You actually need to pass in a Senor object, not just the ID of it.

`Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)`

Answer (score 1):

The method is just deprecated, you have to use

```
registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int)
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but when I casted the first 2 parameters as (SensorEventListener) and (Sensor) it worked. I then realised the problem was that for some reason I had declared the Sensor as type "Object" and not "Sensor", so Eclipse failed to identify the types of parameters.

This worked for me:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener((SensorManager)this, (Sensor)mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

But now I have correctly declared mAccelerometer as type Sensor I no longer need the casts.