# SensorManager.registerListener wants a SensorListener despite its depreciation

Tags: android, eclipse

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
     //super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener((SensorListener) listener,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER
                |SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

private SensorEventListener listener=new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION){
            System.out.println(event.values[0]);
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){

    }
};
```

So the SensorManager.registerListener is where I'm having the issue. Eclipse insists on a SensorListener, and then proceeds to whine when I pass it one because SensorListener is depreciated. I can't seem to get this worked out and would really appreciate some input! I read the previous post and followed the instructions there to no avail. Thank you all very much!

Brad

Comment: Hi, how is your sensorManager object being initialised? Try placing this in the onCreate method:
sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

Comment: public class ShakeHard extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 public String fillMeUpText = "YEA YEA";
 private SensorManager sm = null;
    TextView xView = null;
    TextView yView = null;
    TextView zView = null;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

Comment: Sorry, that did not format correctly at all, I initialize it as null as a class variable, then assign it in main with the following...

sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

Comment: /* also...just as a note, I am aware of the variable discrepancy, my code is using sm as my sensor manager throughout...*/

Comment: Hi, take a look at the post by 'pizzlefou', here:
http://www.anddev.org/accessing_the_accelerometer-t499-s45.html

Comment: Ok, so firstly thank you for your quick responses. I looked into Drainman's posts and was able to get the accelerometer posting info to my screen which was fun :D, however, eclipse is yelling about depreciated methods. It wants SensorEventListeners and whines about SensorListener being depreciated. When I was passing a SensorListener to my sm.registerListener it was working, but whining about depreciation saying that I should be passing it a SensorEventListener. So I tried to update to SensorEventListeners and now the sm.registerListener is complaining that it needs a SensorListener..confusing

Comment: For example, when listener creates a new SensorEventListener:

The method registerListener(SensorListener, int, int) in the type SensorManager is not applicable for the arguments (SensorEventListener, int, int)


and when listener creates a SensorListener:
android.hardware.SensorListener


This interface is deprecated.
Use SensorEventListener instead. 

Class Overview
Used for receiving notifications from the SensorManager when sensor values have changed.

Summary

Comment: Hi, try http://snipplr.com/view/14890/handling-shake-events-on-android-15/  This is ported to the 1.5 SDK, which should be using the SensorEventListener instead of the deprecated method. I remember having this exact problem and I'm trying to find the website which helped me solve it.

Comment: Try http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#wYGukkcNuKc/trunk/AndroidAndGAE20091219/Sensor/ShakerDemo/src/com/commonsware/android/sensor/Shaker.java&q=commonsware&d=4
I believe this is the code that helped me use SensorEventListener.

Comment: Heh, got it. Not sure exactly what the problem was though. I'm going to contribute it to a combination of things:
1)Be sure to implement SensorEventListenor in the class def
2)The SensorManager.registerListener() is pretty picky, be sure to call it from an instantiated SensorManager object, the first parameter is 'this', second is the SensorManager object (I think I mistakenly called the class for a while), and the third parameter is called from the class.

Sorry to take your time on this, and thank you very much for taking your time! The links were definitely a great help! Thanks again!

Brad

Comment: No worries, Brad. I remember running into this problem as well and it was bugging me lol. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem earlier. For me it was a simple fix. I updated to the latest SDK and ADT and simply swapped out the SensorListener with a SensorEventListener

```
sensorManager.registerListener(sensorEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_OREINTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on this post: [android SensorEventListener problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935854/android-sensoreventlistener-problem) take a look at the code here: [Commonsware compass demo](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Sensor/Compass/src/com/commonsware/android/sensor/CompassDemo.java)

I'm stuck on the same thing and it's helping me out